# How to make several Components resize vertically to fit in the available space in CodenameOne?

Tags: layout, codenameone

I have a `Container` which will include a varying number of pictures (`ScaledImageLabel`), ordered vertically. I'd like that the pictures resize so that they never get hidden: they resize so that collectively, they take up te available vertical space.

I tried different layouts but can't figure how to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a grid layout with a non-scrollable container so you would do something like this:

```
parentForm.setScrollableY(false);
parentForm.setLayout(new GridLayout(getComponentCount(), 1));
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I now use a 3 MultiButton instead of 3 ScaleImageButton, that's the only difference with my original question.

Comment: The 3 MultiButton are in a container in a GridLayout (3,1), which is itself in the "Center" region of the Form in a BorderLayout: https://imgur.com/a/4s7Pp
As we see, the 3 MultiButton are not fully visible.

Comment: See gist: https://gist.github.com/seinecle/e5c70904cca0caf24ae256c44514baa4

Comment: The problem isn't the grid. It takes up available space, the problem is the parent container which has also a 3x1 grid. It divides the space precisely to the 3 elements within so the center element doesn't get enough space allocated to it. I think you need a regular scrollable Y to the parent container in this specific case. Alternatively try a border layout with north/south/center if you don't want scrollability but that might impact your landscape game.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I went for a scrollable y, but on iPhone 3 skin and similar low res phones, the Multibutton still get out of the screen on the right - and it is not desirable to have a scroll X there. The app has now stabilized so I ask a new question with all the code for the layout to ask for advice. Thanks again.

Comment: You shouldn't use X scrolling. Sometimes there are just hard physical limits of fitting content into a **much** smaller screen.

Comment: ok... the iPhone3 default skin should probably changed then? I'll show you the example and you'll judge

Comment: The skin is designed to be consistent with the device. I don't see the logic here

Comment: It's just that the iPhone 3 has a low density of pixels so the physical limit your were talking about is hit on this one, but not on larger phones.

Comment: I am for changing the default skin to something like iPhone 6 which is a better representative of today's median device but that might be a problem for developers using lower resolution displays.